# tsfresh package for feature extraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, feature-extraction, tsfresh

I have a dataframe. I would like to extract features based on a time window.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,3,5,6,8,10,12],
                   'id':[793,793,793,793,793,793,793,793,793,793,942,942,942,942,942,942,942],
                   'B1':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,23,24,25,27,30,44,55],
                   'B2':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,23,24,25,27,30,44,55],
                   'B3':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,23,24,25,27,30,44,55]})
time_window = pd.DataFrame({'time':[2,4,6,8,5,8], 'id':[793,793,793,793,942,942]})
```

Here, my time window is

> ```
>         [2,4]--> for participant 793
>         [6,8]--> for participant 793
>         [5,8]--> for participant 942
> ```

My goal is to extract the features on the specified time window for each participant. Therefore, I wrote a function

```
from tsfresh import extract_features

def apply_tsfresh(col):
  for i in range(len(time)):
    col.loc[time_window[i]:time_window[i+1]] = extract_features(col.loc[time_window[i]:time_window[i+1]], column_id="id")
    return col 

extracted_freatures = df.set_index('time').apply(apply_tsfresh)
```

It will extract the features based on the specified time window for each participant. However, I am not getting any results. It provides me an error.

Could you please help me here? I am totally out of any ideas.

My desired output should be look like as:
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KcWB.png)

*Here, the extracted features maybe more than just two. Also the extracted features values maybe different. I am just giving you an example.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, an empty dataframe is created 'extracted_freatures_'.
A cycle is created, step two. Elements are taken from the dataframe 'time_window' column 'time'. The results from 'extract_features' are attached to the 'extract_features' dataframe. Don't ask me how 'tsfresh' works, I don't know.

```
extracted_freatures_ = pd.DataFrame()

df = df.set_index('time')

for i in range(0, len(time_window['time']), 2):
    ind1 = time_window.loc[i, 'time']
    ind2 = time_window.loc[i+1, 'time']
    a = extract_features(df.loc[[ind1, ind2]], column_id="id")
    extracted_freatures_ = pd.concat([extracted_freatures_, a])

print(extracted_freatures_)
```

Output

```
Feature Extraction: 100%|██████████| 6/6 [00:00<00:00, 36.71it/s]
Feature Extraction: 100%|██████████| 6/6 [00:00<00:00, 39.50it/s]
Feature Extraction: 100%|██████████| 6/6 [00:00<00:00, 40.81it/s]
     B2__variance_larger_than_standard_deviation  ...  B3__mean_n_absolute_max__number_of_maxima_7
793                                          1.0  ...                                          NaN
942                                          0.0  ...                                          NaN
793                                          1.0  ...                                          NaN
942                                          1.0  ...                                          NaN
793                                          1.0  ...                                          NaN
942                                          1.0  ...                                          NaN

[6 rows x 2367 columns]
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you wrote `df.loc[[ind1,ind2]]` in  `a = extract_features(df.loc[[ind1, ind2]], column_id="id")`. What actually it does in the double bracket?

Comment: I updated the questions with my desired output appearance. Please have a look on it.

Comment: fancy indexing you can see it  [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html). If you print df.loc[[ind1, ind2]], you will see that the rows is more than two. This extract_features returns two lines at each iteration.

Comment: @pythonhater you have duplicate indexes in 'df', so those indexes after index 10 will also be used. Do you need to access up to 10 index?